Showing markdown code background in "boxed" mode
When reading markdown in markdown-view mode, I'd like the markdown code to be "boxed" in the sense that the code has a different background throughout the entire window width. Currently, if changing the face markdown-code-face, it only affects the text that makes up the code, but you get a jagged background for the right side of the code.
This is what you currently get:

This is what I'd like:

Is there any way of achieving this?

You can find out what face is being used by a certain character by placing your cursor on the character and then doing C-u C-x =.
In this case, you'll find out that the face is markdown-code-face, so try customizing that face and set its extend attribute to t: M-x customize-face RET markdown-code-face, click on Show All Attributes, checkmark the Extend attribute and set its value to On; then Apply to test and Apply and Save to make the setting permanent.
See the description of the extend face attribute in Face Attributes in the Emacs Lisp Reference manual.
